# Inserting clob into varchar(max) using db link in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, plsql, dblink

I have a base64 string of an image in a `clob`  column that i want to store into a `varchar(max)` type column in `sql server`. I am accessing `sql server` `database` using db link in oracle database.

Here is the code i am using.

```
declare
    c clob;
begin
    select base64_clob into c from base64clobtable;
    insert into EMPTRANS_ACTIVE_TEST@attlogdb values(null, null, null,c);
    commit;
end;
```

When i run this statement i am getting this error.

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 71:
PL/SQL: ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Kindly share your thought on how can i insert a `clob` column into `varchar(max)` using db link.

Comment: You can not references to LOBs in remote tables. Instead you can create materialized view to reference to remote tables. Or create a temporary table.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying MR @JSapkota . can you be more specific about what you said above ? Base64clobtable is in my oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

Error is what is states :you have a lob locator that points to a REMOTE LOB.    you can't play with lob over DB link in this way.

I would suggest you to use gloabl temp table.

1)Load the data in GTT in oracle db.
2)Insert into EMPTRANS_ACTIVE_TEST@attlogdb select * from gtt;

```
SQL> create global temporary table foo as select base64_clob from base64clobtable;

SQL> insert into EMPTRANS_ACTIVE_TEST@attlogdb select null, null, null, clob_data from foo;
SQL> commit;
```

Comment: could you add an explanation to your answer, please?

Comment: clob is used to hold huge data....and that may cause issue in your case. I am just suggesting you to do a substr on clob and get the number of characters which you think is max limit of varchar data type in sql server.It may solve your issue as well. you will have to replace "max_limit for sql_server" with size limit of varchar in sql server

Comment: don't include that explanation as a comment, but instead **edit** your answer.

Comment: your edit did not in any way include an **explanation**.

Comment: Sir, I just replaced "max_limit for sql_server" with 8000 characters. Is it that difficult to understand?

Comment: i have asked you to **explain** your answer. to tell people **why** you chose this way, **what** exactly it does, and **how** it solves OPs problem, so future readers may understand your solution.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann- edited the answer and added the explanation and work around for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with the select of the clob from a remote Db you have two solution to get a remote clob

1) create a view on the remote site that selects the dbms_lob.substr. You can then select from that view over the dblink.(MAX 4000 charachter)

2) insert into a local temporary table, copy the lob over to work with it.

Comment: Problem is insert clob into remote db, not select

Comment: if you  copy and paste an answer from another site you should mention this and add a link to this answer https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:950029833940

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But i'm not sure if my solution works. 
If i understand varchar(max) in sql server is equivalent for oracle clob data type. 
Split local your clob into varchar2 chunks and update remote record in loop.

```
 declare
   c clob;
   l_chunk_cnt number;
   v_chunk_size number := 4000;
   v_remote_id  number;
 begin 
  select base64_clob into c from base64clobtable;  
  insert into EMPTRANS_ACTIVE_TEST@attlogdb values(null, null, null,'') returning remote_id into v_remote_id;   
  l_chunk_cnt  := ceil(bms_lob.getlength(c)/v_chunk_size);   
  for rec in (select dbms_lob.substr(c, v_chunk_size, ((level-1) * v_chunk_size) + 1) c_chunk
          ,level
    from   dual
  connect by level <= l_chunk_cnt) loop
      update EMPTRANS_ACTIVE_TEST@attlogdb set clob_column = clob_column||rec.c_chunk where remote_id = v_remote_id;
  end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Thanks you @Arkadiusz update EMPTRANS_ACTIVE_TEST@attlogdb set clob_column = clob_column||rec.c_chunk where remote_id = v_remote_id; gives error. ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG